# Random Access Marker Interface

Tags: java, collections

How Implementation of

> Random Access Marker Interface

is making retrieval operation in **ArrayList** faster? 
Marker Interface requests JVM for faster access or retrieval of values.

What algorithm is JVM implementing for faster access?

Hope You will understand the question now.

Comment: Did none of the links from googling _"java random access marker interface"_ provide the needed information?

Comment: I think he's just confused about the purpose of a marker interface.

Comment: @Thihara "How [does the] implementation of ... [make] retrieval operation in array list fast". Sounds like he wants to know why it makes things faster.

Comment: Really i am not confused about the concepts of Marker Interface @Thihara I just want to know the internal implementation of ArrayList , how it is better for retrieval operation than other collections.

Comment: Just look at the source code of ArrayList?

Comment: I went through the Source Code but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

It tells us that the implementation **supports** fast random access.

That's the purpose of a marker interface. It **marks** an implementation.

To quote the docs

> Marker interface used by List implementations to indicate that they support fast (generally constant time) random access. The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists.

Comment: My question is what internally it is doing to retrievie the values faster.

Answer (score 1):

It marks the implementations of list which can be accessed randomly.

This way a caller can either access the data randomly if that is efficient, or use another means if it is not.

e.g. In AbstractList you have an implementation which can be optimised for RandomAccess or not.

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    return (this instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new RandomAccessSubList<>(this, fromIndex, toIndex) :
            new SubList<>(this, fromIndex, toIndex));
}
```

> What algorithm is JVM implementing for faster access?

The important method is `get(int)` which needs to be `O(1)`

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}
```

calls

```
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

as you can see it just looks up the index in an array so it O(1)

Comment: My question is "What algorithm is JVM implementing for faster access?"

Comment: @HimanshuAwasthi To marked as `RandomAccess` the get(int) needs to be `O(1)`

Comment: @HimanshuAwasthi You might be imagining it is something more significant that it is. For `ArrayList`, it looks up an array by index, not much more than that. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your valuable answer... :)